# Why does Hibernate's DELETE return 1 even when table is empty?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have this very simple piece of code, aimed at deleting only 1 record (if present!) :

```
public String deleteOneRecord(String recordUniqId) { 
  // System.out.println(recordUniqId);
  try {
    String _return =  "recordId " + recordUniqId + " not found.";

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); // commit closes it
    session.beginTransaction(); 
    String hql = "delete from MyTable where record_id= :recordUniqId"; 
    int numDeleted = session.createQuery(hql).setString("recordUniqId", recordUniqId).executeUpdate();          
    if (numDeleted == 1); {
      _return = "Successfully deleted recordId " + recordUniqId;
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return _return;
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
}
```

This code deletes OK the record specified by the Id (and returns 1), but it also returns 1 even when the table is empty.

Why?

Isn't [Query.executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) supposed to return the number of entities updated or deleted?

Comment: Well it should, but it only returns what the JDBC call returns to it. What driver/dialect are you using ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not returning `1`. The issue is, you're having a dangling semi-colon after your `if` statement:

```
if (numDeleted == 1);   // <-- Here
```

This makes the following code block just an independent local block, which will execute no matter what.

Comment: Darn. I knew I needed another pair of eyes. Good catch and thank you so much!